# Spark: Is a col of a datetime on a weekday or weekend?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing Spark code in Python.  I have a `col(execution_date)` that is a timestamp.  How would I turn that into a column that is called `is_weekend`, that has a value of `1` if the date is a weekend and `0` if it's a week day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you had the following spark DataFrame:

```
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|     execution_date|
#+-------------------+
#|2019-08-01 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-02 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-03 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-04 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-05 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-06 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-07 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-08 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-09 00:00:00|
#|2019-08-10 00:00:00|
#+-------------------+
```

**Spark Version 2.3+**

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dayofweek), which will return a number between 1 and 7 (Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dayofweek

df.withColumn("is_weekend", dayofweek("execution_date").isin([1,7]).cast("int")).show()
#+-------------------+----------+
#|     execution_date|is_weekend|
#+-------------------+----------+
#|2019-08-01 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-02 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-03 00:00:00|         1|
#|2019-08-04 00:00:00|         1|
#|2019-08-05 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-06 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-07 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-08 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-09 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-10 00:00:00|         1|
#+-------------------+----------+
```

**Spark Versions 1.5+**

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.date_format`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) with `format = 'EEE'`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df.withColumn(
    "is_weekend", 
    date_format("execution_date", 'EEE').isin(["Sat", "Sun"]).cast("int")
).show()
#+-------------------+----------+
#|     execution_date|is_weekend|
#+-------------------+----------+
#|2019-08-01 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-02 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-03 00:00:00|         1|
#|2019-08-04 00:00:00|         1|
#|2019-08-05 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-06 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-07 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-08 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-09 00:00:00|         0|
#|2019-08-10 00:00:00|         1|
#+-------------------+----------+
```

---

For completeness, the intermediate results of both are shown here:

```
df.withColumn("dow", dayofweek("execution_date"))\
    .withColumn("day", date_format("execution_date", 'EEE'))\
    .show()
#+-------------------+---+---+
#|     execution_date|dow|day|
#+-------------------+---+---+
#|2019-08-01 00:00:00|  5|Thu|
#|2019-08-02 00:00:00|  6|Fri|
#|2019-08-03 00:00:00|  7|Sat|
#|2019-08-04 00:00:00|  1|Sun|
#|2019-08-05 00:00:00|  2|Mon|
#|2019-08-06 00:00:00|  3|Tue|
#|2019-08-07 00:00:00|  4|Wed|
#|2019-08-08 00:00:00|  5|Thu|
#|2019-08-09 00:00:00|  6|Fri|
#|2019-08-10 00:00:00|  7|Sat|
#+-------------------+---+---+
```